# How to measure 10bit SAR ADC 's input Dynamic range after switch 9 time?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, adc, signal-processing

I want to know  10 bit SAR ADC , supply voltage 0.5V , Vcm based , after DAC switch 9 times , how to measure DAC input Dynamic range ? I need to know voltage range  that I can use Voltage to time Converter transfer the voltage to times

Thanks everyone reading[image]

Sample_N = DAC's N node Sample_P=DAC's P node​

Comment: Nice DSO .......

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DSO setting does not match the logic probe voltage of 0 to 500 mV, so it seems you have a 10:1 probe and the DSO will have a setting for that.

Normally your dynamic range is from 0 to Vref and to measure bipolar voltages you set Vcm to Vref/2.  Consult datasheet and link it in question.

Comment: Thanks reply , appreciate, but I want to know accurate number about , final Sample_P ,Sample_N Voltage range , but I don't know how to measure and concept

Comment: which DAC? did you calibrate probe on DSO test point?